# Operation on vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want my program to create and output 4 sets, each having 13 numeric elements.

Expected output is **1.1, 1.2, ..., 1.13, 2.13, ..., 4.13** (set and element is represented as `set.element`):

```
Set  Element
1    1
1    2
 ...
1    13
2    1
2    2
 ...
2    13
 ...
4    13
```

I also want to store this data in a `std::vector` so that I can access and reuse it by using functions `at` or `operator[]`.

My current output is 0. I want to display the output at a particular *index*, say output at index 30.

**Code:**

```
vector<int> storein(52);
int sortn;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
    {
        storein.push_back(j);
        cout << i + 1 << "\t" << j << endl;
    }
}

// cout << storein.size();
cout << storein[30] << endl;
```

**Live example:** http://ideone.com/XcGAyX

Comment: Have a look at [some documentation for `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). That will tell you what `vector<int>storein(52);` and `push_back` do.

Comment: Your code doesn't [compile properly](http://ideone.com/guSODX) :-/

Comment: Sorry, your edits didn't help. It [still doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/dwlvUS).

Comment: [Better now](http://ideone.com/GIilb2) :P ...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, it is a size 52 vector of ints.

Comment: if this is an incorrect code can you tell me how i can store in vector   having 52 storage capacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector<int> storein(52);
```

The vector now has 52 elements.

The calls to `push_back` add *more* elements to the end of the vector. When you refer to `storein[30]`, you find one of the original 52 elements.

Try this:

```
vector<int> storein;
```

In general, when you start to use a new tool, you should try the simplest things you can do, test the results, and build up to more complex operations. This is a vital skill.